# How can you write the following Rails Query in SQL?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I have the following Rails Query:

```
Org.find(:all).each do |org|
    Org.update_counters org.id, :users_count => org.users.length
end
```

For various reasons, like performance, I need to write this in SQL, so I can execute SQL, and not user Rails to make the update. Any ideas how combing the rails loger into sql is possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
Org.update_counters org.id, :users_count => org.users.length
```

Basically does this:

```
update orgs
set users_count = coalesce(users_count, 0) + #{org.users.length}
where id = #{org.id}
```

Unrolling one step:

```
update orgs
set users_count = coalesce(users_count, 0)
                + (select count(*) from org_users where org_id = #{org.id})
where id = #{org.id}
```

Now you've wrapped that in an `Org.find(:all).each` so we just have to push the iteration into the SQL and deal with `#{org.id}`:

```
update orgs o
set users_count = coalesce(users_count, 0)
                + (select count(*) from org_users ou where ou.org_id = o.id)
```

And if you really mean to *set* the `users_count` values rather than *increment* them:

```
update orgs o
set users_count = (select count(*) from org_users ou where ou.org_id = o.id)
```